Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth and same key appearing at different levels
If I have a situation like:
dictionary1 = {
    "level11": {
        "level12": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}
    }
    "level21": {
        "level22": {
              "level23": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1},
         }
    }
}

how do I update all occurrences of:
{"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1} 

to:
{"levelA": 2, "levelB": 3}. 

Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth solves part of the issue but I have a situation more general than that.

Use a recursive function.

At each level, check if the dictionary equals the original value. If so, use dict.update() to replace it with the new value.

Can you please edit your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: How to ask a good question

@Woodford i am observing this type of comments. i had attempted several ways each with some error message or with some logic error which does not yield the correct results what i wanted. how does posting all those attempts help ? how do i even select which one of those attempts to post ?  posting anyone of those would obfuscate the central question i have and give rise to a different set of discussion about the errors i have made.

Let's also use deepcopy()
You can use isinstance() of a dict() and recursively call the _update() function and replace a X dict with a Y dict:
import copy


def _update(d, X, Y):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if v == X:
                d[k] = copy.deepcopy(Y)
            else:
                _update(v, X, Y)


data = {
    "level11": {
        "level12": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}
    },
    "level21": {
        "level22": {
            "level23": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1},
        }
    }
}

X, Y = {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}, {"levelA": 2, "levelB": 3}

_update(data, X, Y)
print(data)

Y.update({"levelA": 20000, "levelB": 30000})

print(data)
print(Y)



Prints
{'level11': {'level12': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}, 'level21': {'level22': {'level23': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}}}
{'level11': {'level12': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}, 'level21': {'level22': {'level23': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}}}
{'levelA': 20000, 'levelB': 30000}



Note
If we don't use deepcopy() and we change Y, then the changes will be reflected in the original dictionary and that may not be what we want.
def _update(d, X, Y):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if v == X:
                d[k] = Y
            else:
                _update(v, X, Y)


data = {
    "level11": {
        "level12": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}
    },
    "level21": {
        "level22": {
            "level23": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1},
        }
    }
}

X, Y = {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}, {"levelA": 2, "levelB": 3}

_update(data, X, Y)
print(data)

Y.update({"levelA": 20000, "levelB": 30000})

print(data)
print(Y)


Prints
{'level11': {'level12': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}, 'level21': {'level22': {'level23': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}}}
{'level11': {'level12': {'levelA': 20000, 'levelB': 30000}}, 'level21': {'level22': {'level23': {'levelA': 20000, 'levelB': 30000}}}}
{'levelA': 20000, 'levelB': 30000}


Assigning the same Y is a bad idea by no comment.

Assigning the sameY is a bad idea.

@nocomment You're absolutely right. My bad.

You can use a recursive function to modify the value if the key you are looking for matches, otherwise call the function if the value is another dictionary.
If you want to modify the values, you can use a recursive function that changes each instance of the key it finds:
def recursive_modify(d: dict, mod_key: str, mod_value: int):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            recursive_modify(v, mod_key, mod_value)
        else:
            if k == mod_key:
                d[k] = mod_value

data = {
    "level11": {
        "level12": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}
    },
    "level21": {
        "level22": {
            "level23": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1},
        }
    }
}

# call to change the data
recursive_modify(data, 'levelA', 2)
recursive_modify(data, 'levelB', 3)

Which returns for data:
{'level11': {'level12': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}},
 'level21': {'level22': {'level23': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}}}

Here is an example that increments the value by 1 every time a key matches.  This is more useful if you need to increment the value, but don't want to dig around in the dictionary to find it first.
def recursive_increment(d: dict, incr_key: str):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            recursive_increment(v, incr_key)
        else:
            if k == incr_key and isinstance(v, (int, float)):
                d[k] = v+1

data = {
    "level11": {
        "level12": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1}
    },
    "level21": {
        "level22": {
            "level23": {"levelA": 0, "levelB": 1},
        }
    }
}

Now to increment levelA twice levelB twice, just call:
recursive_increment(data, 'levelA')
recursive_increment(data, 'levelA')
recursive_increment(data, 'levelB')
recursive_increment(data, 'levelB')

Which modifies data to be:
{'level11': {'level12': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}},
 'level21': {'level22': {'level23': {'levelA': 2, 'levelB': 3}}}}

